# Looking to Condense a prepared statement with multiple foreach loops (PHP, SQLite)

Tags: php, json, pdo, foreach, prepared-statement

I have a [JSON FILE](http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/teamroster/SJS/iphone/clubroster.json) that is parsed and entered into my database with an `INSERT OR IGNORE` plus an `UPDATE` query. The JSON was split into "goalies", "forwards" and "defensemen" so I ended up doing this:

```
try {   
        $db = new PDO('connection stuff');  
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
    } catch (Exception $e) {  
         echo "Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.";
         exit;
    }   
    $json = file_get_contents('http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/teamroster/SJS/iphone/clubroster.json');
    $json = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    $goalie = $json['goalie'];
    $defensemen = $json['defensemen'];
    $forwards = $json['forwards'];

    $query = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO roster2015_2016 ('position','id','weight','height','imageURL','birthplace','age','name','birthdate','number')
              VALUES (:position, :id, :weight, :height , :imageURL, :birthplace , :age , :name , :birthdate , :number)";
    $prepare = $db->prepare($query);

    $query2 = "UPDATE roster2015_2016
              SET position= :position, id= :id, weight= :weight, height= :height, imageURL= :imageURL, birthplace= :birthplace, age= :age, name= :name,
                             birthdate= :birthdate, number= :number
              WHERE id= :id"; 
    $prepare2 = $db->prepare($query2);

    foreach ($goalie as $pd) {
        $a = array (':position' => $position = $pd['position'],
                                ':id' => $id = $pd['id'],
                                ':weight' => $weight = $pd['weight'],
                                ':height' => $height = $pd['height'],
                                ':imageURL' => $imageURL = $pd['imageUrl'],
                                ':birthplace' =>$birthplace = $pd['birthplace'],
                                ':age' => $age = $pd['age'],
                                ':name' => $name = $pd['name'],
                                ':birthdate' => $birthdate = $pd['birthdate'],
                                ':number' => $number = $pd['number']);

        $prepare->execute($a);
        $prepare2->execute($a);
    }

        foreach ($defensemen as $pd) {
        $a = array (':position' => $position = $pd['position'],
                                ':id' => $id = $pd['id'],
                                ':weight' => $weight = $pd['weight'],
                                ':height' => $height = $pd['height'],
                                ':imageURL' => $imageURL = $pd['imageUrl'],
                                ':birthplace' =>$birthplace = $pd['birthplace'],
                                ':age' => $age = $pd['age'],
                                ':name' => $name = $pd['name'],
                                ':birthdate' => $birthdate = $pd['birthdate'],
                                ':number' => $number = $pd['number']);

        $prepare->execute($a);
        $prepare2->execute($a);
    }

        foreach ($forwards as $pd) {
        $a = array (':position' => $position = $pd['position'],
                                ':id' => $id = $pd['id'],
                                ':weight' => $weight = $pd['weight'],
                                ':height' => $height = $pd['height'],
                                ':imageURL' => $imageURL = $pd['imageUrl'],
                                ':birthplace' =>$birthplace = $pd['birthplace'],
                                ':age' => $age = $pd['age'],
                                ':name' => $name = $pd['name'],
                                ':birthdate' => $birthdate = $pd['birthdate'],
                                ':number' => $number = $pd['number']);

        $prepare->execute($a);
        $prepare2->execute($a);
    }
```

As you can see, I am doing the same thing 3 times in a row (1 for offense, defense and goalies). I tried to use an `&&` operator and make just one `foreach` loop, but I guess you are not allowed to do that. That failed attempt was  Can someone link me to a resource of give me a quick idea of what to do? I have tried a few Google and Stack Overflow searches and can't find what I am looking for. [Here is a link to my roster output](http://52.4.65.161/final_project/roster.php). Don't worry about scrolling to the right for the query, that is working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/teamroster/SJS/iphone/clubroster.json');
$json = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$resultArray = array();


$goalie = array();
if (is_array($json['goalie']) && count($json['goalie']) > 0) {
    $goalie = $json['goalie'];
}

$defensemen = array();
if (is_array($json['defensemen']) && count($json['defensemen']) > 0) {
    $defensemen = $json['defensemen'];
}
$resultArray = array_merge($goalie, $defensemen);

$forwards = array();
if (is_array($json['forwards']) && count($json['forwards']) > 0) {
    $forwards = $json['forwards'];
}

$resultArray = array_merge($resultArray, $forwards);

foreach ($resultArray as $pd) {
    $a = array(':position' => $position = $pd['position'],
        ':id' => $id = $pd['id'],
        ':weight' => $weight = $pd['weight'],
        ':height' => $height = $pd['height'],
        ':imageURL' => $imageURL = $pd['imageUrl'],
        ':birthplace' => $birthplace = $pd['birthplace'],
        ':age' => $age = $pd['age'],
        ':name' => $name = $pd['name'],
        ':birthdate' => $birthdate = $pd['birthdate'],
        ':number' => $number = $pd['number']);

    $prepare->execute($a);
    $prepare2->execute($a);
}
```

Comment: That works. I was hoping to find a more simple solution. I would have never thought to append an array to an array. Thank you. I will most likely accept this answer.

Comment: You put in the effort and it works so I will. I wouldn't mind the ability to comment (hint).